# Apache2 ignoring htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I basically want to redirect all www to http.

### In my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ServerName www.rentauto-sofia.com
        ServerAlias rentauto-sofia.com

        ProxyPass / http://rentauto-sofia.com:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://rentauto-sofia.com:8000/
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory / >
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

### My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have tried putting garbage inside the `.htaccess file`, but the apache kind of ignores it. I have enabled the `a2enmod expires` and `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

### Edit:

The file `.htaccess` is located in `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: did you restart apache after enabling the rewrite module?

Comment: Of course I did.